# How to connect my local USB port with Azure virtual machine in Ubuntu?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I am new to Azure, I want to connect my local USB port to Azure VM (for debugging apps in android studio), how can I do this?
I am using AZURE Windows VM on my Ubuntu through Remmina.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, you may look up the supported [RDP Plugin features](https://remmina.org/remmina-features/#rdp-plugin-features) for connecting to your local USB port through Remmina.

As a workaround, if you want to redirect local ports to your Azure Windows VM, it's recommended to use Microsoft RDP client. Then you can simply go to Local Resources---Mores---Ports in a Remote Desktop Connection. Read [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67881b65-6046-4eee-a64b-38c1159d9730/accessing-a-usb-through-an-azure-virtual-machine?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) for more details and upvote [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/8040390-usb-devices-are-not-supported-in-azure-vms) for similar features request.